# How cy.click a subset of buttons

Tags: cypress

I'm testing multiple delete from a table, but to ensure that not all items are deleted by mistake I want to leave the first item. The selector is the same for every row, but I need to filter the selection after fetching. This code deletes all items, works but how do I test with 1 remaining?

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="item"]').click({multiple: true })
cy.contains('button', 'Delete selected').click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice the selected elements

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="item"]')
  .invoke('slice', 1)             // exclude 1st row
  .click({multiple: true})

cy.contains('button', 'Delete selected').click()

cy.get('[data-cy="item"]')
  .its('length')
  .should('eq', 1)
```